# Android sending data and getting ok respeonse but no data on web server

Tags: java, android, http

I hope someone can help.

I have written a simple android app that (attempts) to send an sqlite db to a web server. I am getting a ok response in the logcat but nothing on the web server.

Android code:

```
String urli = "http:localhost/upload.php";

int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
byte[] buffer;
int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;
String lineEnd = "\r\n";
String twoHyphens = "--";
String boundary =  "*****";

File dbDirectory = new File("/sdcard/Databases/");
ArrayList<File> database = new ArrayList<>();
for (File fileEntry : dbDirectory.listFiles())
{
    database.add(fileEntry);
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(urli);

    URL url = new URL(urli);
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

    InputStreamEntity reqEntity = new InputStreamEntity(
            new FileInputStream(fileEntry), -1);

    reqEntity.setContentType("binary/octet-stream");
    reqEntity.setChunked(true);

    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    String response2 = connection.getResponseMessage();
    Log.i("response", response.toString());
    Log.i("response", response2.toString());
```

Heres the logcat:

```
05-17 19:30:31.118 16679-16801/ I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@528d0bdc
05-17 19:30:31.118 16679-16801/I/response: OK
05-17 19:30:31.138 16679-16801/ I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@528d069c
05-17 19:30:31.138 16679-16801/ I/response: OK
05-17 19:30:31.158 16679-16801/I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@528da700
05-17 19:30:31.158 16679-16801/ I/response: OK
05-17 19:30:31.210 16679-16801/I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@5290984c
05-17 19:30:31.210 16679-16801/ I/response: OK
05-17 19:30:31.254 16679-16801/ I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@5290f7c0
05-17 19:30:31.254 16679-16801/I/response: OK
05-17 19:30:31.274 16679-16801/ I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@52915848
05-17 19:30:31.274 16679-16801/I/response: OK
05-17 19:30:31.298 16679-16801/ I/response: org.apache.http.message.BasicHttpResponse@5291b7bc
05-17 19:30:31.298 16679-16801/ I/response: OK
```

I would be eternally grateful if someone could help or point me in the right direction.  I'm going stir crazy trying to figure this out.

Comment: 1) Are you sure the web server is working correctly? 2) Why are you connecting to localhost?

Comment: 1) The URL should read `http://localhost...`, IMHO. 2) I don't really see where you attach `reqEntity` to `httppost`

Comment: Localhost? That will not work. Where is your app running? Where is the server runing? Explain your setup.

Comment: `to send an sqlite db to a web server`. You are just trying to send several files to a server.

Comment: @greenapps to be fair, those files *could* be sqlite databases.

Comment: Indeed. And i think they are. So just files.

Comment: My setup is as follows, I'm running android studio on a linux host with a windows xampp vm running, the localhost is actually the IP address and location of the upload php file. This is all new to me so please bear with me.

Comment: Show the ip you use instead of confusing us with localhost. You did not tell if you use an emulator or a real Android device.

Comment: But why arent you reacting on `I don't really see where you attach reqEntity to httppost`. DaSourcerer was spot on. There is your problem! Even if you are new you could react. So you build a reqEntity and then throw it away without using. So no file sent.

Comment: Again apologies,  Firstly I'm using a emulated device, secondly How do i attach reqEntity to httppost? Cheers